# CentOS6をCentOS7にアップグレード後、yum updateでTransaction check error (nss-pemとnssのconflicts)

Tags: centos, yum

http://a-records.info/upgrade-centos69-to-centos-73/

こちらの記事を参考に、CentOS6をCentOS7にアップグレードしました。
アップグレード自体は完了したのですが、その後yum updateをしようとしたところ、el6関連のパッケージが残っていてエラーになりました。これらのほとんどはyum remove等で解消できたのですが、最後に下記のエラーが残って解消できず、 yum update が実行できません。

> Transaction check error:
>    file /usr/lib64/libnsspem.so from install of nss-pem-1.0.3-5.el7_6.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package nss-3.36.0-9.el6_10.x86_64

「el6」というのがあったので yum remove しようとしたのですが、

> エラー: "systemd" を削除しようとしています、保護されています
>   エラー: "yum" を削除しようとしています、保護されています

と表示され、削除できませんでした。
ならばと yum install nss とやってみたのですが、

> 一致したパッケージ nss-3.36.0-7.1.el7_6.x86_64 はすでにインストールされています。更新を確認しています。
>   何もしません

となってしまいます。

インストールされていますと書かれてはいますが、 yum list installed や rpm -qi 等で調べてみてもel7のものは存在せず、el6のものしかインストールされていないようです。

ちなみに yum update nss とやってみましたら、

> No packages marked for update

となり、こちらでも解決できませんでした。

アップグレードツールのせいかもしれませんが、このようなインストール済みパッケージのバージョンが誤認されるケースは通常起こり得るのでしょうか。
また、今回遭遇しているこのエラーを解消する方法はあるのでしょうか。

CentOS7をクリーンインストールした方が良いとも思うのですが、事情がありクリーンインストールではなくアップグレードを完遂させたいと考えております。
何卒皆様のお力添えを頂きたく存じます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 更新の前後でOSの正確なバージョンはそれぞれいくつなのでしょうか？ / 参考にされたページにもある通り、6.xが新しいほど7.xへのアップグレード時にパッケージのバージョンで齟齬が起きる可能性があると書いてあります。 / パッケージのうち、el6_10などの部分はあくまでターゲットのOSを区別するための**文字列**扱いで、バージョン番号ではありません。質問の環境だと nss-**3.36.0-9**.el6_10 と nss-**3.36.0-7.1**.el7_6 で前者のほうがバージョンが進んでおり、まさに参考にしたサイトに書いてある問題が起きているように見えます。

Comment: やったことはないですが yum distribution-synchronization で 6.5 にダウングレードして、それから el7 にアップグレードしてみると できそうな気がします。ただ、ダウングレードは 普通にやっても恐らく失敗しますので まずはそちらを調べながらやってみると良いかも。

Comment: cubickさん、コメントありがとうございます。調べてみましたが、CentOS6.9 -> 7.6のアップグレードでした。ご指摘の通り、参考サイトの問題が起きているようです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: take88さん、コメントありがとうございます。ダウングレードという発想はなかったです。検討してみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 7 の nss-3.36.0-7.1.el7_6.x86_64 より CentOS 6 の nss-3.36.0-9.el6_10.x86_64 の方がバージョン・リリース番号が新しいため、yum でアップデートできないようです。

nss-3.36.0-7.1.el7_6.x86_64.rpm ファイルをダウンロードして、
`rpm -Uvh --oldpackage nss-3.36.0-7.1.el7_6.x86_64.rpm` または `rpm -Uvh --force nss-3.36.0-7.1.el7_6.x86_64.rpm` で nss を置き換えられませんでしょうか？
依存関係でダメかもしれませんが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。rpmファイルをダウンロードしてコマンド実行してみましたが、依存関係の欠如でエラーになってしまいました。やはりアップグレードは難しいようですので、クリーンインストールも含めて検討してみます。ありがとうございました。